# Return an unsigned long from vector of ints c++

Tags: c++, vector, unsigned, bigint

What's the best method for returning an unsigned long from a vector of ints? I'm working on a BigInt class in c++ and I'm storing the large numbers in a vector. I want to write a method that will return this vector as a standard long, provided it isn't larger than unsigned long can hold. Thanks

Comment: An `unsigned long` and an `int` are generally the same size so presumably all you could do is return the least significant vector member (i.e. `vector::back()`).

Comment: Well, on LP64 platforms, a `unsigned long` is 64-bits and an `int` is 32-bits. Also, depending on how his class stores negative numbers, he may need some code to deal with that. (Short answer: It depends on how the rest of your class works, but there's probably one obvious way and it's likely the best.)

Comment: For this class, I'm going to ignore negative numbers, so I can assume that all values in the vector are positive

Comment: Just in case "on LP64 platforms" sounds like some obscure C++ implementation along the lines of "there was this Cray in the 70's that I can completely ignore as irrelevant to any code I ever write": 64 bit versions of Linux and OSX both use LP64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines, assuming the ints are stored in the vector with the least significant first:

```
size_t bits_in_int = std::numeric_limits<int>::digits;
size_t bits_in_ulong = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::digits;

unsigned long accumulator = 0;
size_t bits_so_far = 0;
for (unsigned long i : the_ints) {
    size_t next_bits = bits_so_far + bits_in_int;
    if (next_bits > bits_in_long) { /* failed, do something about it */}
    accumulator += (i << bits_so_far);
    bits_so_far = next_bits;
}
return accumulator;
```

Notes:

1) In practice you could save some bother because the number of loops is going to be either 1 or 2 on any vaguely normal-looking C++ implementation. So you could just write a case where you return `the_ints[0]` and a case where you return `the_ints[0] + (the_ints[1] << bits_in_int)`.

2) I've been lazy. Because `int` is signed and `unsigned long` is unsigned, you can actually fit at least one `int` *plus* the least significant bit of another `int` into an `unsigned long`. For example you might find `bits_in_int` is 31 but `bits_in_long` is 32.

So actually in the "failed" case there is one last hope for peace, which is that (a) there is only one `int` left to process, and (b) its value fits in the remaining bits of the result. But like I say, I'm lazy, and I think I've shown the components you need to put together.

For this reason if no other, you should probably use a vector of `unsigned int` for your BigInt. It's not required that the width of `unsigned long` is a multiple of the number of bits in `unsigned int`, but it might be strange enough that you can ignore it.

Update for base 10 digits, stored most significant first:

```
if (the_ints.size() <= std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::digits10 + 1) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (int i : the_ints) ss << char(i + '0');
    unsigned long result;
    if (ss >> result) return result;
}
/* failed, do something about it */
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I wasn't able to get that to work. I created a test vector like so: vector<int> testVector{1,2,3};. Then I replaced "the_ints" in your code with testVector and when I cout I get 13835058059577131009 when I expect 123

Comment: @Mike: well for starters you aren't storing the integers in the vector with the least significant first (hundreds is *more* significant than units). You could iterate the vector backwards using `rbegin()` and `rend()`. Secondly I didn't realise you were storing decimal digits. That makes it somewhat more complicated to determine whether the value stored in the vector is in range or not, because it's not solely a question of the number of bits. Finally, using that `testVector` and my code you should have hit the `/* failed */` case and handled it, not output anything.

Comment: Sorry I'm so late getting back to you on this. I was going to accept your answer earlier, but I became busy and didn't login to SO for awhile. Your first solution seemed very elegant, but didn't quite help me because of how I was storing the ints, but your updated answer for base 10 digits was just what I needed. I'm going to try updating my class and use both methods just to see which one I like better. Thanks again!